# Scrollbar in Tkinter Notebook frames

Tags: python, canvas, tkinter, scrollbar

I cant get my scrollbar to show up correctly in my tkinter notebook. I need a scroll for each page

```
root = tk.Tk()
root.title('Client Intake Form')

n = ttk.Notebook(root)
f1 = ttk.Frame(n)
f2 = ttk.Frame(n)
f3 = ttk.Frame(n)
n.add(f1, text='Page 1', compound=tk.TOP)
n.add(f2, text='Page 2', compound=tk.TOP)
n.add(f3, text='Page 3', compound=tk.TOP)
n.pack()

canvas = tk.Canvas(f1, width=1000, height=1000, relief='raised')
canvas.pack()

scroll = tk.Scrollbar(canvas, command=canvas.yview, orient=tk.VERTICAL)
canvas.config(yscrollcommand=scroll.set, scrollregion=(1000,0,1000,1000))
scroll.pack(side=tk.RIGHT, fill=tk.Y, expand=True)

#######PAGE 2#######
page2 = tk.Canvas(f2, width=1000, height=1000, relief='raised')
page2.pack()

######PAGE 3######
page3 = tk.Canvas(f3, width=1000, height=1000, relief='raised')
page3.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

I want the scrollbar on the right side of each page.

Comment: Why are you putting it inside the canvas if you want it on all pages?

Comment: oh, i just don't know how, period. or where to put it? but yes, i want it on all pages.

Answer (score 1):

> **Question**: I cant get my scrollbar to show up correctly in my tkinter notebook.

- I want the scrollbar on the right side of each page.
  Using the `.pack` manager is possible, but if you use the `.grid` manager instead, you get simpler laid out what you want.
- I need a scroll for each page
  Instead of **repeating yourself**, define your own widget and reuse it on all your `Notebook` tabs.

---

- Define a `class YScrolledFrame` by inheriting form `(tk.Frame)`.
  This `Frame` grows as large as the `parent` widget allows.
  To behave the `Scrollbar` **dynamic**, you have to use `.bind('<Configure>', ...`

  ```
  class YScrolledFrame(tk.Frame):
      def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
          super().__init__(parent, *args, **kwargs)
          self.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
          self.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

          self.canvas = canvas = tk.Canvas(self, bg='white', relief='raised')
          canvas.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nsew')

          scroll = tk.Scrollbar(self, command=canvas.yview, orient=tk.VERTICAL)
          canvas.config(yscrollcommand=scroll.set)
          scroll.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky='nsew')

          self.content = tk.Frame(canvas)
          self.canvas.create_window(0, 0, window=self.content, anchor="nw")

          self.bind('<Configure>', self.on_configure)

      def on_configure(self, event):
          bbox = self.content.bbox('ALL')
          self.canvas.config(scrollregion=bbox)
  ```
- Define a `class Notebook` by inheriting form `(ttk.Notebook)`.
  This allows to access a `Notebook tab` by it's `label text`.

  ```
  class Notebook(ttk.Notebook):
      def __init__(self, parent, tab_labels):
          super().__init__(parent)

          self._tab = {}
          for text in tab_labels:
              self._tab[text] = YScrolledFrame(self)
              # layout by .add defaults to fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True
              self.add(self._tab[text], text=text, compound=tk.TOP)

      def tab(self, key):
          return self._tab[key].content
  ```

> **Usage**:

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk

class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        notebook = Notebook(self, ['Page 1', 'Page 2', 'Page 3'])
        notebook.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nsew')

        # Fill content, to see scroll action
        tab = notebook.tab('Page 1')
        for n in range(20):
            label = tk.Label(tab, text='Page 1 - Label {}'.format(n))
            label.grid()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    App().mainloop()
```

***Tested with Python: 3.5***